# Red 'x' symbol next to solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I am working with Visual Studio. When I create a project, in the solution explorer there is a red cross.

What does it mean? How can I take it away?

Below is the screenshot of the red 'x' symbol next to the Solution.

[image: The x red symbol next to the Solution]

Answer (score 3):

It means the file has a pending edit for a deleted item. You can get rid of the red x by pressing "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer toolbar